# PHP: How to calculate person age in months

Tags: php, function

I have searched for this but did not find a perfect function in php. I want to get a php function that calculate person age only in months.

For example:

```
less then one month old.
5 months old.
340 months old.
```

Thanks

Comment: A good answer will on 2010-03-01 answer '1' if the person is born 2010-01-31, and '0' if the person is born 2010-02-02.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using PHP's [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) (available from 5.3.0), that's pretty easy:

```
$birthday = new DateTime('1990-10-13');
$diff = $birthday->diff(new DateTime());
$months = $diff->format('%m') + 12 * $diff->format('%y');
```

Now `$months` will contain the number of months I've lived.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use $diff->format() over accessing the y and m properties of the DateInterval directly?

Comment: Nope. You can do that as well if you wish.

Comment: I don't see any mention of those properties in the documentation. Using undocumented features is generally a bad idea as they are more likely to change in the future.

Comment: @Ruben: You're right. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. It's been added now and should show up online within the next week: http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=301510

Answer (score 2):

```
$birthday = new DateTime("June 21st 1986");
$diff = $birthday->diff(new DateTime());
$months = ($diff->y * 12) + $diff->m;

var_dump($months);
```

Something along these lines?

Answer (score -2):

**Note: this assumes the input is a precise decimal of years. For example, 1.5 years old.**

If you want years to months, where the person inputs their ages as `$years`

```
$month = $years*12;
```

If you want months to years, where the person inputs their age as `$months`

```
$year = $months/12
```

Comment: This is not completely accurate, considering the fact that the months aren't distributed evenly (28, 29, 30, 31 days per month).

Comment: Also, if a person is born in January and now is July, the computation would be wrong by 7 months.

Comment: not if you assume $years can be input as a decimal.. e.g. 1.5 years etc